# Facebook image URL showing undefined on server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grails

I am trying to fetch profile images from facebook  into our app, I am able to retrieve the whole profile picture album from facebook and I can save the selected image from facebook into my local data base.. It is working perfectly in my local system , but when I moved this to our development server  image url showing "undefined". But it is fetching the array, and the count of the profile pictures it showing is also correct on the Development server.  Trying to implement it using angular JS and grails version=2.4.2. Is there any version support issue?

```
FB.api('/me/albums?fields=id,name', function(response) {

    for (var i=0, l=response.data.length; i<l; i++){
        var album = response.data[i];
        if (album.name == 'Profile Pictures'){
            FB.api('/'+album.id+'/photos', function(photos){    
                if (photos && photos.data && photos.data.length){   
                    for (var j=0; j<photos.data.length; j++) {
                          var photo = photos.data[j]; 
                          $("<div class='row' ><div class='col-md-6 photos'><span><input class='FBprofile' type='radio' name='FB_Profile'  /><img id='FB_Profile_"+j+"'  src='"+photos.data[j].picture+"' alt=''><span class='photo_text'></span></span></div></div>").appendTo("#fb_photos_id");
                    }
                }                                                                        
            });
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code I am using ..

Comment: can you show your resulting html?

Comment: while trying to print the array I got dis :::: photos.data[j].picture>>undefined . and I am getting the response array from FB as well..